# rails routes with scope locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, locale

I have add another language to my app. So, I am using the following routes for the static pages:

```
scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|br/ do
  get "static_pages/about"
  match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
  ...
end
```

it is working fine, resulting:

```
http://localhost:3000/en/about
```

However, each time I switch between languages it returns the full path instead of the match:

```
http://localhost:3000/en/static_pages/about
```

The way I am switching languages:

```
#links
<%= link_to (image_tag '/england.png'), url_for( locale: 'en' ) %>
<%= link_to (image_tag '/brazil.png'), url_for( locale: 'br' ) %>  

#application controller
before_filter :set_locale
def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale]
end

def default_url_options(options={})
  { locale: I18n.locale }
end
```

It is a problem because I am using the current path in my CSS file, so each time I switch language it is messing up the layout:

```
<%= link_to (t 'nav.about'), about_path, class: current_p(about_path) %> 

#helper
def current_p(path)
   "current" if current_page?(path)
end
```

**I am trying to find a way to return the `match` route when switching languages. Any idea?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem combining `match` and `get`.
So, instead of:

```
scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|br/ do
  get "static_pages/about"
  match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
  ...
end
```

I have now:

```
scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|br/ do
  match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about', via: 'get'
  ...
end
```

**EDIT** - Thanks to [sevenseacat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560215/sevenseacat), an easier and shorter solution:

```
scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|br/ do
  get '/about' => 'static_pages#about'
  ...
end
```

Comment: It would be a bit shorter (and easier) to use `get '/about' => 'static_pages#help'`.

Comment: what is the difference of using `(:locale)` vs `/:locale` ?

Comment: @ArnoldRoa, it makes :locale optional
"If you don't want to force the use of a locale in your routes you can use an optional path scope (denoted by the parentheses)"
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html